# Books that explain Linux Ubuntu in detail?

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a lot of problems with Linux . I currently downloaded Ubuntu. I really wonder what does 0.0 mean, how to combine command like `ls -alh` ( which one should come first), what is the command short for (eg. wc). Any books that tell us all these little things?

Comment: http://debian-handbook.info/ (free online).Not about Ubuntu per se, but Ubuntu is basically Debian with some added bugs.  There is also the "Debian System" by Martin Krafft, but that is not free. However, looking at your question, it looks like you are perhaps more in need of a basic Unix book. There are lots of choices. Go to a bookshop and browse. Check out Amazon etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux Command Line (TLCL) book which written by William Shotts is a great reference for newbies, and you will learn basic linux commands ( even UNIX ).

http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php